# How do you remove the wrapping DIV from Page Builder elements?

Tags: magento2, page-builder

Page builder seems to like wrapping everything in a `<div>` tag.  This is causing an issue especially with HTML elements which for some reason is automatically wrapped with...

```
<div data-content-type="html" data-appearance="default" data-element="main" style="border-style: none; border-width: 1px; border-radius: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;" data-decoded="true">
    ...
</div>
```

How do we override this to remove the wrapping `<div>`?

Comment: I am also looking for the answer. @ScruffyPaws did you get any?

Comment: Magento Support said it wasn't possible to remove this which is a shame.  I was told that PageBuilder requires these. I wish they used the WordPress "Gutenberg" approach by using unobtrusive HTML comments instead of vomiting out DIVs everywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly, after contacting Magento Support, they said it wasn't possible to remove this because PageBuilder relies on these. I wish they used the WordPress "Gutenberg" approach by using unobtrusive HTML comments instead of vomiting out DIVs everywhere...

Answer (score 0):

Since that still there is no options for disabling wrapping DIV, I will point to the solution suggested [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/282109/how-to-remove-extra-divs-in-my-page-builder-cms-blocks) by [BeardMan](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/83326/beardman):

In page builder when creating CMS block add class=> ignore-div then add style for it

```
.ignore-div {display: contents;}
```

This will ignore wrapper, eg. behave like that it no exist.